# Why does this link hover effect start from the middle and not the left?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why in the code below, the link hover effect starts from the middle instead of going from left to right. Can someone please explain why this happens?

```css
.orange-link {
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orange-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: .25s linear;
}

.orange-link:hover:before,
.orange-link:focus:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<p>Visit the official rules <a class="orange-link" href="#">here</a> on how to send in a write-in entry.</p>
```

Comment: @ATomCalledStu will do nothing because the OP is using the scale property

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the default origin of CSS transforms is the center of the element.

> "By default it is at the center of the element and can be moved. It is used by several transforms, like rotations, scaling or skewing, that need a specific point as a parameter."
>   — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms

The line spans the full width, but is scaled to 0 (from the center) to start. Then, on hover, the line is scaled back up to it's original full width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `transform-origin: top left;` to .orange-link:before

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hwkrexo/)

Unless you specify the transform-origin, it will default to the center.

Comment: I guess `transform-origin" left;` would suffice, actually.

Comment: The question is about understanding why it is from the center. The asker does not mention wanting it to be from the left.

Comment: Ok, explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are scaling the element. It scales from the middle because the origin is in the middle (by default).
 As [seen here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

> By default, the origin of a transform is "50% 50%", which is exactly in the center of any given element.

The possible fix can be to use the width

```
.orange-link {
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orange-link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0 !important;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.25s linear;
}

.orange-link:hover::before,
.orange-link:focus::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.orange-link {
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orange-link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0 !important;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.25s linear;
}

.orange-link:hover::before,
.orange-link:focus::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p class="read-or-listen-to-excerpt">
  Visit the official rules <a class="orange-link" href="#">here</a> on how to send in a write-in entry.
</p>
```

Or you can even shift the origin by `transform-origin: bottom left;`  and do this

```css
.orange-link {
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orange-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: .25s linear;
}

.orange-link:hover:before,
.orange-link:focus:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<p class="read-or-listen-to-excerpt">
  Visit the official rules <a class="orange-link" href="#">here</a> on how to send in a write-in entry.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `transform-origin` so that it starts from the left:

```css
.orange-link {
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orange-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: .25s linear;
    transform-origin:left bottom;
}

.orange-link:hover:before,
.orange-link:focus:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<p class="read-or-listen-to-excerpt">
  Visit the official rules <a class="orange-link" href="#">here</a> on how to send in a write-in entry.
</p>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of why it starts from the center.

Comment: @sean I should have actually mentioned that the default is `center center`.